# Jquery validate plugin custom addMethod help, for checkboxes

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I have created a JS fiddle to briefly outline what i am trying to accomplish. You can view it here:
http://jsfiddle.net/BNjby/1/

As you can see there are 5 different options for the "role". their values will always stay the same. Basically, I need to add js & validation so that, if the role Trainee is selected, other roles are automatically deselected (or show validation error message); and likewise if  one of the other roles is selected, Trainee is deselected.

My current Jquery looks like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#registerForm").validate({
            rules: {
                'roles[]':{
                    required:true,
                    profile_checkboxes: true
                }
            },
    });
  });

$.validator.addMethod("profile_checkboxes", function (value, element) {
    if($(element).is(':checked') && value == 5){
        $(element).siblings(':checkbox').attr('checked',false);
        return true;
    } else if ($(element).is(':checked') && value != 5){
        if($(element).siblings().val() == 5){
            console.log($(this))
        }
    }

}, "");
```

and the html:

```
<h1>Form Validation Example</h1>
    <form id='registerForm' name='registerForm' method='post' action='' >  
        <div class="control-group">
        <label for="role">Role</label>  
             <div class="controls" id="role_names">


            <label class="checkbox"><input type="checkbox" name="roles[]" value="5" /> Trainee</label>                                      
<label class="checkbox"><input checked="checked" type="checkbox" name="roles[]" value="4" /> Supervisor</label>                                 
<label class="checkbox"><input type="checkbox" name="roles[]" value="6" /> Faculty</label>                                  
<label class="checkbox"><input type="checkbox" name="roles[]" value="7" /> Coordinator</label>                                  
<label class="checkbox"><input type="checkbox" name="roles[]" value="3" /> Manager</label>                                      </div>
                    </div>
       <button class="pull-right btn-success btn" type="submit"><i class="icon-check"></i>Save Changes</button>
    </form>
```

Been stuck on this one a few weeks, I thought it was time to ask for a bit of help. Thank you much :)

Comment: How can we help when we can't even see your HTML markup?

Comment: sorry about that, I just updated my question.

Answer (score 0):

I've run into this before. jQuery validator doesn't fully support using field name arrays because it relies on the field names to be unique.  One way you can solve this is by setting your field names to roles[0], roles[1], roles[2], etc.  This gives jQuery validator something unique to bind to and normally whatever language your posting the data to (php, for example) will still accept those as arrays when processing the post.